# Redirect from non-www to www and force SSL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'd like to force all http traffic to https, and also always force www.

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This seems to correctly work when the url does not contain www. So http://mydomain.com correctly redirects to https://www.mydomain.com.

However, it is not correctly redirecting to https when the www part is present. So, www.mydomain.com is not redirecting to https://www.mydomain.com

**Edit**
I have got this working with two rewrite blocks:

```
# Force ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

No idea if this is acceptable or not, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Use your `domain name` and not `HTTP_HOST` in the rewriterule so that way it won't matter if www is there or not and you can use 1 rule. You can have two rewrite rules but just use `OR`. I think you were looking for is this.

```
# always redirect to www and/or https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```